Plot only a small element of area of a surface with pgfplots
I want to plot only small element of area of a sphere. That is, the parametric surface

I tried the following but it rather outputs a complete sphere, and I don't understand why.
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,axis equal,
axis on top,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
domain=50:52,
y domain=60:62,
xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-2.0,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
]
\addplot3 [surf]
({cos(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},{sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(y))},{cos(deg(y))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


deg() converts radians to degrees, but you are alreacy using degrees.  2 radians is a lot of surface.

Now I see it. You can post an answer, if you want.

You might want to change your POV.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,axis equal,
axis on top,
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
domain=50:52,
y domain=60:62,
%xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
%ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-2.0,
samples=30,
samples y=20,
]
\addplot3 [surf]
({cos(x)*sin(y)},{sin(x)*sin(y)},{cos(y)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


